# Select Query in if else in Postgres Sql

Tags: sql, postgresql

something like ths

```
if(1=1)
select * from Table_a
else
slect * from Table_b
```

without using functions

I am trying something like this

```
DO $$ 
DECLARE   
  a integer := 10;   
  b integer := 20;  
BEGIN    
  IF a >b THEN     
    select  * from online.fandi_workflow_options ;   
  else 
    select  * from online.credit_workflow_options ;   
 END IF;
END
$$;
```

Can anyone help me here

Comment: Well that example can be simplified to `select * from table_a` - what exactly are you trying to do there? What is the real condition you want to test?

Comment: Please only add **one** version tag for the real Postgres version you are using.

Comment: I can achieve this using function .But i dont want to use function.I just want based on condition query should return different result

Comment: Again: show us the **real** condition you are trying to apply here. Your example makes no sense. And please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking text tables. ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Comment: Edited.But here I am getting some error.

Comment: You are describing a very rare case where the information is either in one table or the other. It would be more typical to have one table `online.workflow_options` with a type column representing 'FANDI'  or 'CREDIT'. The query would be straight-forward then.

Answer (score 2):

```
select  * from online.fandi_workflow_options 
where a > b 
union
select  * from online.credit_workflow_options
where a <= b
```

You can usually replace a logical "if" with a "where" clause; in your case, you're selecting from two different tables, so you have to use a union. This query only works if both tables have the same columns - if not,  you can select explicit column names, and add "bogus" columns to each select statement to make them identical.

Comment: `UNION ALL` seems appropiate here. (except for the case of a or b being NULL)

Comment: Scenario is to check if the column exists in the table then we have to do a select query

Comment: @Madhu, your question is really hard to answer unless you provide specifics. Your example doesn't make much sense - by providing hard coded values for a and b, you're always going to get the same execution path. "If the column exists" will also always give the same execution path unless you're dynamically adding columns to tables.